# Delete a row from a JavaFX table using context menu

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this JavaFX table in which I want to delete a row when I click wit the right click of the mouse context menu and choose "Delete".

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainApp extends Application
{

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Processor", "72"),
            new Person("RAM", "78"),
            new Person("HDD Free Space", "890"),
            new Person("Lan Adapter NIC 1", "36"),
            new Person("Lan Adapter NIC 2", "67"));

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        //Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        //stage.setWidth(850);
        //stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(false);
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory
            = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>()
            {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p)
                {
                    return new EditingCell();
                }
            };

        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("Credentials");
        //firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(300);
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(50);
        //firstNameCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(2)); // w * 1/2

        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
                {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Value");
        //lastNameCol.setPrefWidth(300);
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(50);
        //lastNameCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(2));  // w * 1/2

        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
                {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName)
        {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

    }

    class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String>
    {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit()
        {
            if (!isEmpty())
            {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit()
        {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText((String) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty)
            {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (isEditing())
                {
                    if (textField != null)
                    {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                }
                else
                {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setContextMenu(intiContextmenu());
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField()
        {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2)
                {
                    if (!arg2)
                    {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString()
        {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    public ContextMenu intiContextmenu()
    {

        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        contextMenu.setOnShowing(
            new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
            {

                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println("showing");
                }
            }
        );
        contextMenu.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("shown");
            }
        });

        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("About");
        item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("About");
            }
        });
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Preferences");
        item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Preferences");
            }
        });

        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Delete row");
        item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Delete row");
            }
        });

        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, item3);

        return contextMenu;

    }

}
```

The problem is how I can delete the Java Object from the Observable list by using the context menu? Maybe I need to get the `Credentials` value and use it as key to delete the row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Context menu for JavaFX table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801940/context-menu-for-javafx-table)

Comment: The duplicate link mentioned by James_D has been voluntarily removed by the author

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the solution from [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/7758918):

```
private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();

...

table.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {  
        @Override  
        public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> tableView) {  
            final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();  
            final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();  
            final MenuItem removeMenuItem = new MenuItem("Remove");  
            removeMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {  
                @Override  
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {  
                    table.getItems().remove(row.getItem());  
                }  
            });  
            contextMenu.getItems().add(removeMenuItem);  
           // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:  
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(  
                    Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())  
                    .then((ContextMenu)null)  
                    .otherwise(contextMenu)  
            );  
            return row ;  
        }  
    });
```

It was very helpful for me.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this compare brian's solution

Comment: @olyjosh care to explain why this is the better alternative?

Comment: @BlueWizard The post is almost a year. I wish i could remember everything wrong with the second approach but the quick one I can remember is that solution will always pop a context menu even on an empty table because that wasn't taken care of as the event listenener was bounded to the table so every time you write click on the table, the context menu is fired and irrespective of the size of the observable list that makes up such table. That's been taken care of with the code snipet that pop's the context menu as follow.  

Also looking at the

Answer (score 7):

When you click, that row gets selected.  This is the simplified code I use.

```
TableView<LineItem> tv = new TableView<>(items);
Stack<LineItem> deletedLines = new Stack<>();
tv.setUserData(deletedLines);
MenuItem mnuDel = new MenuItem("Delete row");
mnuDel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        LineItem item = items.get(tv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        if (item != null){ 
            String fn = item.getFirstName();
            deletedLines.push(items.remove(item));
        }
    }
});
MenuItem mnuUnDel = new MenuItem("Undo Delete");
mnuUnDel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        if (!deletedLines.isEmpty())items.add(deletedLines.pop());
    }
});
tv.setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(mnuDel,mnuUnDel));
```

Comment: I managed to get the result by the code `getTableView().getItems().remove(getItem());  `. But I need also to make SQL query by getting the Java Object which will be remove. How I can get the Java class which I will remove?

Comment: And then how I can get the firstName and lastName?

Comment: I get cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFirstName()
  location: class String

Comment: @PeterPenzov I don't see how your code deletes a row.  Your getItem() must just return a cell.  Use my code, I modified it to keep the FirstName.  Using your code you'd need something like `getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex()).getFirstName();`

Comment: I get `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` when I click on a empty row. How I can prevent this?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Look to invariants answer.  I don't usually put error checking in examples but I'll edit my answer

Comment: @brian If I'm using Own Class object in the table view. will that require to override the Equals method to remove the row from the tableview?

Comment: @UnKnown I don't know what you mean.  I never use equals, I just remove the selectedItem.

Comment: @brian as I use collections in java. we have to override equals and hashCode() methods in our class to remove or find particular object from the collections. That's why I'm asking this for tableview's items.

Comment: @UnKnown TableView uses an ObservableList<S>, I think if you can wrap your class in an ObservableList then it's ok.  You should test it or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

get the selected item and delete it .

```
   MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Delete row");
        item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Delete row");
                Person p = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                if(p!=null) {
                    data.remove(p);
                }
            }
        });
```